# Преобразование строки с датой в Angular

Tags: angular2, angular

От Django Rest в Angular мне прилетает объект, одно из полей которого - строка с датой в формате `'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm'`.

Я хочу сохранить ее как Date в компоненте, чтобы преобразовать (скорректировать часовой пояс, формат вывода даты и т.д.) и потом использовать в интерфейсе.

Подскажите, как мне преобразовать подобную строку в тип даты. Пробовал через `new Date(...)`, через `Date.parse(...)`, но выдается `Invalid Date`. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Конечно, можно просто отредактировать строку до понятного Angular состояния, например так : `'...'.split('.').join('/')`, но это явный костыль. Может есть способ подсказать парсеру формат строки?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению замена точки на прямой слеш не поможет - нужно еще месяца с днями поменять местами... А это уже велосипед костылей(

Comment: Пока что рашил зайти с другой стороны - возвращаю строчку в правильном формате изменив сериализатор на бэке. Но все равно есть проблема с парсингом дат на фронте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку MomentJS.

```js
const example = moment("06-03-2012 12:00", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").toDate();

console.log(example);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Наверно это лучшее решение. Единственное, я взял подобный пакет из npm, там он называется просто moment. Спасибо за помощь!